# Choosing WebView2 Fixed Version for Distribution

Tags: wpf, microsoft-edge, webview2, microsoft-edge-chromium

We are moving from CefSharp to WebView2. Because of certain requirements, we are thinking of going ahead with the fixed version where the updates can be controlled by us. Now, on Microsoft's official distribution page we have 3 options available - x86, x64 and ARM64. We have users who use different combinations of OS and CPU architecture. One example is 32 bit Windows 10 Pro running on a 64 bit Intel processor. Here is where I am confused. Which one to ship to agents depending on their combinations of OS and CPU architecture. Can anybody help here? Here are the combinations -

[image: WebView2 Fixed Version Mapping]

I have not tried out and hence may be a blunt question - can x86 distributable be a safe bait for all these combinations? If yes, then what are the trade-offs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think x86 distribution is safe. If 32-bit OS is running, the entire system acts as purely 32-bit. It's impossible to use any 64-bit piece of code, so 64-bit applications won't work. You can also check [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/482192/is-it-possible-to-run-64-bit-software-on-a-32-bit-operating-system): If you want to run 64-bit app on 32-bit OS, you have to install a VM or something. I think that's not what you want.

In conclusion, I think you should choose the WebView2 Fixed Version according to the OS version.

Comment: We tried out x86 WebView2 fixed version runtime on both 32 bit and 64 bit Windows OS-s and seems to work. However, we have not done any performance comparison of x86 vs x64 packages on 64-bit OS-s.